# Looking for irrational Numbers Proof

Tags: irrational-numbers

$a,b,c,~$and $d$ are rational numbers.
$b>0$ and $d>0$
the $\sqrt{b}$ and the $\sqrt{d}$ are both irrational.

if $a+\sqrt{b}=c+\sqrt{d}$

show that $a = c$ and $b = d$.

I know that a=c and b=d intuitively, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What's the data and what's the question??

Answer (score 1):

$a-c=\sqrt(d)-\sqrt(b)$
If this is true, then that means $\sqrt(d)-\sqrt(b)$ is rational because rational numbers are closed under subtraction.
The only way for this to be true is that $\sqrt(d)-\sqrt(b)=0$.

Comment: I don't think it's obvious that $\sqrt{d}-\sqrt{b}=0,~$ in order for it to be rational. For example $x=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$ are both irrational, but $x-y=1$.

Comment: This can be fixed by noticing that $$\sqrt d + \sqrt b = \frac{d^2 - b^2}{a - c}$$ is also rational; now sum some things.

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks!

Comment: @T.Bongers (d-b)/(a-c) not (d^2-b^2)/(a-c)

Comment: @user152341 Yes, you're quite right.

Comment: can you show how it equals (d-b)/(a-c)

Comment: Multiply the equation a−c=(√d)−(√b) by √d+√b